# teamviewer 10 not compatible to remote control version 11?

Tags: compatibility, teamviewer

i have a commercial license of `teamviewer 10`.
when trying to remote control a host that has `teamviewer 11` installed i'm getting an error message that says "incompatible version".

is there any way to connect to remote machines with higher versions?
so far i have not seen any restrictions being mentioned officially.

PS:
i have observed this problem on both, windows and mac os.

Comment: Evidently No, its incompatible with lower versions.

Comment: I note that someone has down-voted my answer today, though it was correct at the time of asking and is strictly still correct today, though now of course the upgrade option would recommend TV12.

Answer (score 3):

TeamViewer clients can log into earlier revisions of servers, but not vice versa. This is true across all platforms.

You have 3 choices:-

1. Upgrade the TV10 client to TV11 - this is probably the best option, but not the cheapest.
2. Downgrade the TV11 server to TV10 - you may be able to do this free of charge, but it might not suit the other clients.
3. Ignore the TV10 client and instead log into http://www.TeamViewer.com to use the Web Client.